# Removing the name of the column in the final graph when creating a Kaplan Meier curve

Tags: r, visualization

In the image below you can see how the lines are labeled as "Scenario = actual", "Scenario=Best", & "Scenario = Worst". I can not for the life of me find away to make it so that it shows you how to return it as only "Actual", "Best" and "Worst" without including the name of the column = "Scenario".

[image]

Does anyone know which command would allow me to edit the graph this way?

Graph was found on: https://towardsdatascience.com/kaplan-meier-curves-c5768e349479 and accuratly visualises my problem.

I have tried using different labs and lab functions as well as remove the name of the variable.

Comment: Can you add the code that you are using to generate the plot, including what packages you are using?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the labels of the legend by modifying the `legend.title parameter` inside the `ggsurvplot()` function. Instead of passing an empty string " " you can pass a vector of labels that corresponds to the levels of the `Scenario` variable in the same order.

Code used as example on the [website](https://rmvpaeme.github.io/KaplanMeier_intro/):

```
surv_object <- Surv(time = toy_dataset$Followup , event = toy_dataset$Eventtype)
fit1 <- survfit(surv_object ~ Scenario, data = toy_dataset)

j <- ggsurvplot(fit1, data = toy_dataset, xlim = c(0,11), conf.int = FALSE,  risk.table = "nrisk_cumcensor", legend.title = " ", tables.theme = theme_cleantable(), break.time.by = 2,  censor.shape = c("|"), censor.size = 6)
```

Here is an example of how you can change the labels of the legend:

```
j <- ggsurvplot(fit1, data = toy_dataset, xlim = c(0,11), conf.int = FALSE,  risk.table = "nrisk_cumcensor", legend.title = c("Actual", "Best", "Worst"), tables.theme = theme_cleantable(), break.time.by = 2,  censor.shape = c("|"), censor.size = 6)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `legend.lab` option in `ggsurvplot()`

Example:

```
ggsurvplot(fit, data = df, risk.table = TRUE, legend.lab=c("Actual", "Best", "Worst"))
```